# XSLT 1.0 split variable string to populate specific tags

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am transferring data from one xml format to another with xslt 1.0. In the input xml, address is in a single field as a string separated by spaces. As far as I can tell, it can come in the following formats considering the identifiers in brackets [] are optional.

```
<Field Name="address"...>number [cardinal-dir] name st-type [unit#]</Field>
```

OR

```
<Field Name="address"...>number [cardinal-dir] name st-type APT APT#</Field>
```

so the data may look like:
  "123 3RD AVE" or "123 NE 3RD AVE" or "123 NE 3RD AVE APT 321" ... you get the picture.

And I need it to appropriately populate the following output format:

```
<mstns:Address>
    <mstns:HouseNumber>123</mstns:HouseNumber>
    <mstns:StreetName>NE</mstns:StreetName>
    <mstns:StreetType>AVE</mstns:StreetType>
    <mstns:Apt>APT</mstns:Apt>
</mstns:Address>
```

I've seen some similar posts about tokenizing strings in xlst 1.0 but combined with the variable input I'm a bit lost.

Comment: A street's name, I presume, can have any number of words. If you have a list of all possible values for the direction and the street type, then perhaps this could be used to parse the contents correctly. Otherwise it may be impossible.

Comment: P.S. Which XSLT 1.0 processor will you be using? You could really use some extension functions here, if your processor supports them.

Comment: Good point about the variable number of words in the street name -- that adds even more of a challenge @michael.hor257k. I'm not sure what the processor being used is -- it's embedded in a monstrous program, but I'll look into it. I'm also going to ask if it can be updated.

Comment: See here how to identify your processor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr/25245033#25245033

Comment: Okay, using that, I determined the processor is "Microsoft" and the xslt version it supports is "1."

Comment: That's too bad, because Microsoft does not support any extension functions other that `node-set()`. However, you may be allowed to dip into another language. -- How about those two lists of allowed values I asked about?

Comment: This looks like a pretty good list of possible street types: https://www.gimme-shelter.com/steet-types-designations-abbreviations-50006/ -- I could use a script to break it down into all the possibilities separated by commas (or any other format needed). As far as the cardinal directions, I'm pretty sure they are limited to 8 directions -- N, E, S, W, NE, NW, SE, SW -- and probably with the possibility of them being spelled out, North, East, Northwest etc.

Comment: I am afraid you are looking at a ton of work, with iffy results. I will try and post a sketch later, but personally I would look for another tool to accomplish this task. This is assuming it can be accomplished at all. Not all omelettes can be restored to eggs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, this is an awful lot of work and the quality of the result will depend on how consistent your data is.

Assuming that:

1. the first word (and only the first word) is the street number;
2. the second word **may** be a street direction identifier, from a known list of street direction identifiers;
3. the street name is followed by a street type identifier, from a known list of street type identifiers,

you could use the following stylesheet as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0 (+EXSLT node-set)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Field[@Name='address']">
    <!-- tokenize to words -->
    <xsl:variable name="tokens">
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="words" select="exsl:node-set($tokens)/token" />

    <!-- street direction exists? -->
    <xsl:variable name="street-direction-exists" select="$words[2]='N' or $words[2]='E' or $words[2]='S' or $words[2]='W' or $words[2]='NE' or $words[2]='NW' or $words[2]='SE' or $words[2]='SW'" />

    <!-- find position of street type -->
    <xsl:variable name="street-type-index">
        <xsl:call-template name="get-street-type-index">
            <xsl:with-param name="words" select="$words"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- output -->
    <Address>
        <HouseNumber>
            <xsl:value-of select="$words[1]"/>
        </HouseNumber>
        <xsl:if test="$street-direction-exists">
            <StreetDirection>
                <xsl:value-of select="$words[2]"/>
            </StreetDirection>
        </xsl:if>
        <StreetName>            
            <xsl:for-each select="$words[1 + $street-direction-exists &lt; position() and position() &lt; $street-type-index]">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </StreetName>
        <StreetType>
            <xsl:value-of select="$words[number($street-type-index)]"/>                     
        </StreetType>
        <xsl:if test="count($words) > $street-type-index">
            <Unit>
                <xsl:for-each select="$words[position() > $street-type-index]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Unit>
        </xsl:if>
    </Address>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' '"/>
    <token>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
    </token>
    <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="get-street-type-index">
    <xsl:param name="words"/>
    <xsl:variable name="street-types">
        <street-type>AVE</street-type>
        <street-type>STR</street-type>
        <!-- add more types here (or use an external XML document for them) -->
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$words[last()] = exsl:node-set($street-types)/street-type">
            <xsl:value-of select="count($words)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$words">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="get-street-type-index">
                <xsl:with-param name="words" select="$words[position() != last()]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following test input:

**XML**

```
<Fields>
    <Field Name="address">123 Old Oak Tree AVE</Field>
    <Field Name="address">45B NE Broadway STR</Field>
    <Field Name="address">6789 Maple Syrup AVE Room 800</Field>
    <Field Name="address">1024 W Three Elm Trees AVE APT 321</Field>
    <Field Name="address">1024 False AVE Maria STR Unit 8071</Field>
</Fields>
```

the result will be:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Fields>
  <Address>
    <HouseNumber>123</HouseNumber>
    <StreetName>Old Oak Tree</StreetName>
    <StreetType>AVE</StreetType>
  </Address>
  <Address>
    <HouseNumber>45B</HouseNumber>
    <StreetDirection>NE</StreetDirection>
    <StreetName>Broadway</StreetName>
    <StreetType>STR</StreetType>
  </Address>
  <Address>
    <HouseNumber>6789</HouseNumber>
    <StreetName>Maple Syrup</StreetName>
    <StreetType>AVE</StreetType>
    <Unit>Room 800</Unit>
  </Address>
  <Address>
    <HouseNumber>1024</HouseNumber>
    <StreetDirection>W</StreetDirection>
    <StreetName>Three Elm Trees</StreetName>
    <StreetType>AVE</StreetType>
    <Unit>APT 321</Unit>
  </Address>
  <Address>
    <HouseNumber>1024</HouseNumber>
    <StreetName>False AVE Maria</StreetName>
    <StreetType>STR</StreetType>
    <Unit>Unit 8071</Unit>
  </Address>
</Fields>
```

---

**Note**: You may need to use Microsoft's own `node-set()` extension function, instead of EXSLT.